# ¿Por que se esta imprimiendo el valor de 0?

Tags: c

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo en C

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    int num, cociente, a, b, c, d;
    printf ("Evaluación de expresiones\n\n");
    a = 10; b = 4; c = 5; d = 1; num = 0;
    cociente = (num = a*b)/(num + c + d);
    printf("Cociente vale %d\n", cociente);
    printf("num vale %d\n", num);
    printf("\n\nTerminación normal del programa.\n");
}
```

Me gustaría saber porqué se esta imprimiendo el valor de 0 en cociente, se que el operador paréntesis tiene mayor prioridad y si hay dos se ejecuta de izquierda a derecha, entonces el primero es `(num = a*b)` si este parentesis tiene prioridad asumo que debe resolverle lo que hay dentro primero, como hay una asignacion y una multiplicacion, la multiplicacion tiene mayor prioridad y se resuelve primero, luego se hace la asignacion a num, quedando dentro del primer parentesis la variable num y con valor de 40.

posteriormente se resuelve el 2do parentesis, si num tiene 40 se suma con c + d y queda un valor de 46 en el segundo parentesis, luego se resuelve la division entre los dos valores, 46/40, una vez resuelto se asigna el resultado a cociente.

Me podrias explicar donde esta mi error de analisis, Gracias de antemano

Comment: Dado el tipo del error, dudo mucho que la pregunta/respuesta sea de utilidad para nadie mas. Voto para cerrarla como *error tipográfico*.

Answer (score 2):

El error acabo de notarlo, es muy pavo. 
`(num = a*b)` vale menos que `(num + c + d)`. Por ende siempre te dara 0.

Comment: Ah cierto jajajaja con razon, yo estaba resolviendolo como 46/40 y era al reves...

Comment: Asi es :D Intente usar float o double pero me daban valores MUY raros. No me llevo mucho con con C.

Comment: Considera poner un fragmento de código que solucione el problema del usuario y @EmiliOrtega, si la respuesta soluciona tu problema marcarla como solución.

Comment: Hay otro error más importante: (num=a*b) no está secuenciado antes de (num+c+d)

Comment: @ninjalj no entiendo a que te refieres :o

Answer (score 0):

1er problema:

```
int cociente = (num = a*b)/(num + c + d);;
                ^^^^^^^^^
```

¿Dirías que `num = a*b` se ejecuta antes o después que `num + c + d`?

- Si se ejecuta antes, entonces:

  ```
  num = 10 * 4 = 40
  cociente = 40/(40 + 5 + 1) = 0
  ```
- Si se ejecuta después, entonces:

  ```
  cociente = 40 / 0 + 4 + 5 = 40 / 9 = 4
  ```

**NO** deberías bajo ningún concepto modificar y usar una variable en la misma instrucción. El compilador tiene total libertad (respetando la prioridad de operadores) para determinar el orden de ejecución de las operaciones que componen una instrucción. ¿Cuánto vale `b`?

```
int a=1;
int b = a++ + ++a * a++;
```

2º problema:

```
int num = 0, a = 10, b = 4, c = 5, d = 1;
int cociente = (num)/(num + c + d); // elimino la multiplicación por claridad
```

El tipo `int` no usa decimales. Ante una división el resultado aparecerá truncado (si el resultado es 0.9999 obtendrás 0). Para evitar este problema tienes que utilizar tipos en coma flotante, a saber `float` o `double`:

```
float cociente = ((float)num)/(num + c + d);
```

Por supuesto, para poder sacar el resultado correcto por la consola tendrás que indicar a `printf` que el número es en coma flotante en vez de un entero:

```
printf("Cociente vale %f\n", cociente);
                      ^^ <--- AQUI
```

Comment: El compilador no sólo tiene total libertad ara determinar el orden de ejecución de las operaciones, esto es UB, así que el compilador tiene total libertad para hacer cualquier cosa, como dicen algunos, tiene libertad incluso para hacer que salgan demonios volando de tu nariz: http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html

Comment: @ninjalj UB quiere decir que como cada compilador puede organizar la ejecución como mejor crea el resultado obtenido variará de un compilador a otro.

Comment: no, eso sería si fuera _Unspecified Behavior_. En este caso es _Undefined Behavior_, y el compilador tiene permiso para generar código incorrecto (e.g: actualizar medio valor de `num`, leer `num`, actualizar el resto de `num`)

Comment: @ninjalj ¿y que diferencia hay? En un caso el compilador elige como solventar la situación y en el otro también

Comment: En el caso de _Unspecified Behavior_, el estándar tiene que dar varias posibilidades, y el compilador elegir una. En el caso de _Undefined Behavior_, el compilador puede hacer cualquier caso, incluyendo dar error al compilar, dar error en tiempo de ejecución, o generar código incorrecto.

Comment: @ninjalj pero estás conmigo en que al final, en caso de funcionar, es el compilador el que va a determinar cómo, ¿no?

Comment: @eferion me re jodiste con este codigo `int a=1;
int b = a++ + ++a * a++;`  como hace el compilador para interpretar eso :S? supuestamente me da 13 el resultado de b en el compilador

Comment: @EmiliOrtega no se trata de saber cómo da ese resultado ya que es dependiente del compilador. La idea a transmitir es que ese tipo de operaciones no son seguras y es mejor evitarlas

Comment: @eferion ok amigo, gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En la expresión `cociente = (num = a*b)/(num + c + d);`, `(num = a*b)` no está secuenciado antes de `(num + c + d)`

Según el estándar de C, §6.5 ¶2, si una modificación de un objeto (= región de memoria, en este caso la región de memoria denominada por `num`) escalar no está secuenciada con respecto a un acceso al valor de ese mismo objeto , se produce Comportamiento No Definido (UB = *Undefined Behavior*).

La regla completa es: si un efecto secundario (modificación de un objeto, acceso a un objeto volátil, modificación de un fichero o llamada a función que realice alguna de las operaciones anteriores) sobre un objeto escalar no está secuenciado con respecto a otro efecto secundario sobre ese mismo objeto o cálculo de valor usando el valor de ese mismo objeto, el comportamiento no está definido.

Cuando se produce Comportamiento No Definido, el estándar no prescribe ningún comportamiento. El compilador podría ignorarlo, dar un error, o incluso **producir código incorrecto**.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me quedo claro que no debo inicializar adentro XD pero sigo sin entender bien eso de que `(num = a*b)` no está secuenciado antes de `(num + c + d)` . Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: El estándar de C define algunas relaciones de orden. Una de ellas es secuenciado-antes-de, que es una relación de orden parcial dentro de un hilo. Por ejemplo, en `a || b`, `a` está secuenciado antes de `b`, pero en `a + b`, `a` no está secuenciado con respecto a `b`.

Comment: cierto pero en este caso `(num = a*b)/(num + c + d);` `num = a*b` si esta secuenciado antes que `(num + c + d);` porque los paréntesis tienen prioridad y son evaluados de izquierda a derecha :0 o me equivoco?

Comment: La relación secuenciado-antes-de no tiene nada que ver con el orden de precedencia de las operaciones. Es una relación que se utiliza para varias cosas, por ejemplo, para definir la visibilidad de los accesos a objetos cualificados como volátiles, y junto a otras relaciones de orden dentro de un hilo, y entre distintos hilos, para definir el modelo de consistencia de memoria del lenguaje.

Comment: Las operaciones que están secuenciadas se pueden consultar en el Anexo C del estándar de C.